# Why does this Javascript Prototype code fail?

Tags: javascript, prototype, typeerror

I'm a little bit new to javascript and I came across this error while writing a game. It stumps me since this function seems the same as all of the other functions, yet, it doesn't work.

```
function Game() {}
Game.prototype.loadGame = function(x) {
  this.cvs=document.getElementById(x);
  this.cvs.height=480;
  this.cvs.width=640;
  this.sprites=[];
  this.ctx=cvs.getContext("2d");
};
Game.prototype.update = function() {
  console.log("u");
};
Game.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.drawCircle(320, 240, 10, "green")
};
Game.prototype.drawCircle = function(centerX, centerY, radius, color) {
  this.ctx.beginPath();
  this.ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
  this.ctx.fill();
};
Game.prototype.tick = function() {
  this.update();
  this.draw();
};
Game.prototype.Init = function() {
  fps=60
  this.loadGame("cvs");
  setInterval(this.tick, (1/fps)*1000);
};
g = new Game();
g.Init();
```

I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'update'`

Any idea as to how to fix this?

Comment: In the future, when asking questions, I highly recommend providing some context as to what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using setInterval(), so your tick function isn't getting the 'this' that you expect. You need to do this instead:

```
Game.prototype.Init = function() {
    var that = this;
    fps=60
    this.loadGame("cvs");
    setInterval(function() { that.tick.call(that); }, 1);
}
```

Google for "javascript this" or "javascript call" or "javascript apply" to get more info.

Comment: `call` is not required here, `that.tick()` would be enough.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks, I didn't realize that. I learned something about this/that just now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and I know `this` can be really tricky!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is dynamic, and depends on how the function is called. Since you're using the canvas, we can assume `bind` is available, so this should work:

```
setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), (1/fps)*1000);
```

Note: you might also want to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) for a better frame rate.